# React Class Component setState undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am attempting to update a variable from "" to a string of text with an onClick method in React.
I've approached this several different ways following examples on the web and Youtube but all are resulting in various error messages.

This is the latest attempt and I'm receiving an error message that it cannot set properties of undefined setting set state & it' pointing to the line that reads "super(props).

Can you please let me know what is wrong with this approach?

```
import React,{Component} from "react";

//Declaring variable globally as I was receiving error messages previously
let response = "";

class Track extends Component{
        constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        //Setting the initial state
        this.state = {
         response: "",
          
        };
    }
    
    //Not sure why I'm adding this as some tutorials did not have this but nothing else was working and I came across one with this so I'm attempting it.
    componentDidMount(){
        response = "";
    }
//This function takes the variable from "" and updates it to the string below
    autoResponse(){
    this.setState=({response : "This is not a valid tracking #"})
 }
     
    render(){  
     
    return(<>
   
<input placeholder="Enter Tracking #"></input>

<button onClick={this.autoResponse}>TRACK</button> {/*This is for the setState function. I tried preventDefault() but it stated it's not defined*/}
<div className="response-cntr">
    <p className="response-text">{this.state.response}</p> {/*Should display the updated variable after the onClick*/}
</div>


        </>)
    }

}

export default Track;
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using react functional components, especially if you're new to react. Functional components are in the process of replacing class components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need the global variable `response`.
2. No need for the `componentDidMount` either, you already set the initial state in the constructor.
3. `setState` is a function, so you need to call it and not assign something to it
4. use an arrow function for the `autoResponse`, if you intend to pass it as a prop to other components, so that it retains the correct `this`.

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";

class Track extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //Setting the initial state
    this.state = {
      response: ""
    };
  }

  autoResponse = () => {
    this.setState({
      response: "This is not a valid tracking #"
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (<>
      <input placeholder="Enter Tracking #"></input>
      <button onClick={this.autoResponse}>TRACK</button>
      <div className="response-cntr">
        <p className="response-text">{this.state.response}</p>
      </div>
     </>);
    }
  }

  export default Track;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below, it has the update that the component class extends React.Component, also a few other obvious fixes. BTW like mentioned by other users, when starting off with React it would be a lot easier to get going with function components, rather than jumping right into Class ones...The learning curve would be much less steeper...

```
import React from "react";

class Track extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        //Setting the initial state
        this.state = {
         response: "",
          
        };
    }

    autoResponse(){
        this.setState({response : "This is not a valid tracking #"})
    }
     
    render(){  
     
    return(<>
   
<input placeholder="Enter Tracking #"></input>

<button onClick={this.autoResponse}>TRACK</button> {/*This is for the setState function. I tried preventDefault() but it stated it's not defined*/}
<div className="response-cntr">
    <p className="response-text">{this.state.response}</p> {/*Should display the updated variable after the onClick*/}
</div>


        </>)
    }

}

export default Track;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `=` after `setState`. Try like below,

```
 autoResponse(){
    this.setState({response : "This is not a valid tracking #"})
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Writing `this.setState = ({})` which is wrong instead write `this.setState({})` bcz set State is a Function just remove that `=`